# Did LibreOffice key-bindings to select an entire row change?

Tags: libreoffice

Like most LibreCalc users (I guess), Ctrl+Space to select an entire column of cells and Shift+Space to select an entire row is like second nature. Recently I noticed that Shift+Space wasn't working on one of my machines while it worked on the other. Just today, the other machine got affected as well.

It appears to me that this might have been pushed with an update, which first made it to my first computer a few weeks back, and then to the second one today. The version that I'm using right now is 7.1.1.2.

Any idea if they changed the key-binding, or by any chance (very unlikely though) is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/libreoffice/comments/m2fyvn/did_libreoffice_keybindings_to_select_an_entire/gqj3wx2), [this bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140841) has already been reported and is being tracked.